# Error pointing Route 53 domain to Glide app (app.glideapp.io)

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-route53

we have a domain listed on Route 53. This domain previously pointed to a webpage sitting in an S3 bucket. We now want to point our domain to our Glide app instance, and have followed the steps on Glide's side to create an A record, AAAA record, and TXT record in the DNS of the domain. I also removed the two A records for the S3 bucket. But we are having no luck. Could someone please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: "we are having no luck" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? What are exact settings of your R53, buckets, glide app?

Comment: Apologies, new to stackoverflow. I'm not entirely sure what the exact issue or error is. This is the error when you try access the domain: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

As you would, I have added the necessary records for the externally hosted app to my route 53 DNS records for the domain, but it doesn't seem to be propagating/recognizing the endpoint.